Notepad++ Tab key makes cursor jump to end of whitespace-only line
If I have a line that contains just tab characters, and the cursor is in column 1, hitting the Tab key moves the cursor to the end of the line, and appends another tab character. Can this behaviour be turned off?
I use NPP just for note-taking, not for programming, so this behaviour is inappropriate.

You can change this to insert spaces instead. Is that what you want, or do you not want tab to do anything? If not, what do you want tab to do?

AFAIK, it is not possible. You will have more chance asking Notepad++ developpers

@LPChip I want the tab key to insert a tab character at the start of the line, and for the cursor to move to the end of that new tab character - that is, to behave the same as when typing any other key

@StuartN are you absolutely certain that it does not do that already?

@jsotola: I confirm this strange behaviour. Just try it.
